# ASP.NET for a basic browser game

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

beginner programmer - basic C#, first year of university going too slow in terms of actually learning programming. i'm looking at creating framework for a basic browser game, in the vein of [urbandead](http://www.urbandead.com/) and the now dead nexuswar. because i'm a student i already have visual studio 08 for free - because of this, and my experience with C#, is it worth it to choose ASP.NET/ADO.NET over PHP/mySQL for this kind of project?

Comment: Too subjective for this site.  You should ask at http://programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: You might probably get Visual studio 2010 for free as well. Asp.net is the better choice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET is a great choice, but I highly recommend not starting with something as complicated as Massively Multi-Player Web-Based game. Go with something waaaaay simpler, and work your way from there.. Keep in mind that in order to build a nice looking web site you should also be good at client side programming (HTML,JavaScript, maybe jQuery etc.) which will take quite a lot time to learn as well.
As to ASP.NET vs. PHP.. The web is filled with religious wars about which is better (naturally that depends on how you define "better").
Oh, and one last thing if you haven't started on ASP.NET yet I recommend checking out ASP.NET MVC 2, which will teach you some best practices and at least one very useful design pattern, all of which are extremely important for being a good programmer.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.Net got all it takes for your project. IMO the best choice. But it's fairly complicated even for somehow experienced programmers. (Graphics, handling multiplayers, ...) I suggest you not to expect a near release at least.
Try to find some sample on the net to get a grip on what you're trying to do. It'll make it easier to find the right way.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably never recommend PHP to someone trying to learn programming in general, as I feel PHP's language/framework design is full of WTF's (that is, it sucks) and therefore would be a high risk of steering the learner wrongly.